# How can I resolve my issue with TWebBrowser Post data?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, twebbrowser

I have a issue when using TWebBrowser to Navigate and post data to a web server.

What happens is that when I initially setup the post data and navigate to the page all the information passes over fine.  After filling out some information and clicking a button to process a request, the server attempts to process the request but everything just freezes..

[image]

At this screen..  The odd thing is that out of the thirty or so times I have tried this two times it has worked. ( gone through without freezing )  So i'm not sure what would be accounting for the inconsistencies.

Now If I generate this data and send it to the server via a get request just putting everything in the link it works every time.. On Chrome IE etc..

I thought that maybe the issue was with the post data so I tried to do a get request using the TWebBrowser but it still froze on me.

```
Browser.WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://test.com/ts/testAPI.asmx/Process?'+EncodedDataString);
```

Also while in the **TWebBrowser** - if I hit the start over button which clears most of the post/get data and then enter it all in myself and then process the information it works every time without freezing.

So the only thing I can come up with is that the freezing only seems to occur when sending post/get data via the TWebBrowser...  But works on the TWebBrowser when no data is sent.

I'm assuming the server is trying to run some sort of jquery or javascript when it freezes but i'm not sure.

Below is my code for reference.

```
EncodedDataString := 'username='+FileForm.Firm.FieldByName('USER').AsString+
'&password='+FileForm.Firm.FieldByName('PASS').AsString+'&action='+action+
'&token='+eToken+'&retname='+HTTPEncode(MaskEditRetName.Text)+
'&retaddress1='+HTTPEncode(MaskEditRetAddr.Text)+
'&retcity='+HTTPEncode(MaskEditRetCity.Text)+
'&retstate='+HTTPEncode(MaskEditRetState.Text)+
'&retzip='+HTTPEncode(MaskEditRetZip.Text)+
'&accountno='+HTTPEncode(MaskEditAccount.Text)+
'&amount='+HTTPEncode(MaskEditAmount.Text)+
'&date='+HTTPEncode(MaskEditDate.Text)+
'&paymenttype='+HTTPEncode(paymentType);

PostData := VarArrayCreate([0, length(EncodedDataString)-1], varByte);

for i := 1 to length(EncodedDataString) do
PostData[i-1] := ord(EncodedDataString[i]);

Headers := 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'#10#13;

Application.CreateForm(TBrowser,Browser);

Browser.WebBrowser1.Silent := True;

Browser.WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://test.com/ts/testAPI.asmx/Process',
     EmptyParam, EmptyParam, PostData, Headers);
```

Comment: You can find it out by yourself by comparing the traffic between your PC and the server doing a _normal browser post_ and doing the post from your code, for example, with Wireshark or other sniffer. The answer is there, but for us here is very hard to tell what's wrong without that vital information, at least it is for me.

Comment: I'll see what I can do about getting that information.  If you could help me analyze it I would appreciate that.  I plan to add it to the bottom of my question when I get it.

Comment: Don't forget to escape (by that `HTTPEncode` function) also the values coming from your database as well as the rest, `action` and `eToken` parameter values (if needed).

Comment: @Trevor, When you have the values, compare it by yourself and hopefully you'll figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: there are a lot of HTTP Sniffers outside. I used Membrane Monitor but there are better apps. WireShark and Microsoft Net Monitor maybe even better...